# SQL: Como puedo agrupar por (Filename, status & id) y solo traerme el grupo de registros que cumplan con status = 0 y omitir el grupo completo si no

Tags: sql, postgresql, post

Tengo una pregunta, ¿cómo puedo hacer una consulta que seleccione y agrupe todas las filas por filename y donde todas las filas tengan un `status` de `0`, SELECCIONE si una tiene una fila con un `status` que no sea `0`, el SELECT no devuelve ningún registro de la agrupación por filename.

Input Table:

```
id(Key) filename - order - messagein - messageout - status
  1        a1         101     p1          p1           0
  2        a2         102     p2          p2           0
  3        a1         103     p3          p3           0 
  4        a2         104     p4          p4           1
  5        a2         105     p5          p5           0
```

Output Select

```
id filename - order - messagein - messageout - status
 1    a1         101     p1          p1           0
 3    a1         103     p3          p3           0
```

La selección omite todo el grupo al que pertenece el nombre de archivo `a2` porque una de las filas en su grupo tiene un `status = 1`

Cualquier ayuda sería apreciada. Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

La clausula que estas buscando es algo trivial.. si un filename esta en la lista de filename que tienen status 1, entonces omitis eso.

Para hacer eso.. podes usar la clausula NOT IN en tu where, y compararla con un query que traiga los filenames a omitir.

Agrega en tu where

```
filename NOT IN (select filename from tabla where status = 1)
```